# Java Client com.softlayer.api.service.product.Package getItemPrices(), getConfiguration() is empty

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

1. I can list all the packages and narrow down a package object using a packageId.

`ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey);
Package.Service service = Package.service(client);
List<Package> packages = service.getAllObjects();
chosenPackage = pkg;`

2. The chosenPackage, shows a valid address chosenPackage:com.softlayer.api.service.product.Package@41a0aa7d
3. Now, I want to list the chosenPackage.getItemPrices(), chosenPackage.getConfiguration() etc and all these values are empty.
4. I did not find any method setMask() or withMask() methods for the com.softlayer.api.service.product.Package. I might just work, if I can set the mask.
5. Can you provide some small code, to get the itemPrices? I am using SoftLayer Java Client.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example please:

```
package com.softlayer.api.Package;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.Package;

/**
 * This script retrieves a all packages from SoftLayer_Product_Package::getAllObjects method
 * and their item prices and configuration
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Package
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class GetPackages {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to get all packages and their item prices
     */
    public GetPackages() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);

        // Define SoftLayer_Product_Package service
        Package.Service packageService = Package.service(client);

        // Declare and object mask
        packageService.withMask().itemPrices();
        packageService.withMask().configuration();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try {
            for(Package pack : packageService.getAllObjects())
            {
                System.out.println(gson.toJson(pack.getItemPrices()));
                System.out.println(gson.toJson(pack.getConfiguration()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of GetPackages method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetPackages();
    }


}
```

Please, let me know any doubt or question that you got about it.

**References**:

- [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getAllObjects](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects)

Comment: Thank you! I did make some progress using this link: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this example.

```
package SoftLayer_Java_Scripts.Examples;

import java.util.List;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.Package;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.Item;

public class GetProductItemsById {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String username = "set me";
    String apikey = "set me";
    ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey);

    Package.Service service = Package.service(client);

    try
    {
      List<Package> packageList = service.getAllObjects();

      for(Package pack : packageList){
        System.out.println("------- Package: " + pack.getName() + " - Id: " + pack.getId());

        service = Package.service(client, pack.getId());
        List<Item> itemList = service.getItems();

        for(Item item : itemList){
          System.out.println("Item description: " + item.getDescription());
          System.out.println("Item Id: " + item.getId());
        }  
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Script failed, review the next message for further details: " + e); 
    }
  }
}
```